# Random walk with same directions and different step sizes

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Let $X\sim e^{iU}$, where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0, 2\pi]$. Define $\chi_1, \cdots, \chi_t$ as i.i.d. random variables with the same distribution as $X$.

Consider the following two random walks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the same direction but different step sizes:

$$R1:= \sum_{n<t}\frac{\chi_n}{n^{\sigma}}$$
and
$$R2:= \sum_{n<t}\frac{\chi_n}{n^{1-\sigma}},$$
where $0<\sigma<1$.

For a given $\epsilon>0,$ is it possible to calculate or bound the probability that both $R1$ and $R2$ end up within an $\epsilon$-vicinity of zero at time $t$?

Notably, when $\sigma = 1/2$, $R1$ and $R2$ are equal.

Here is an example: [image]
We took $\sigma=0.3$ and the endpoints of $R1, R2$ are around $0.5$-vicinty of $(0, 0)$.

Comment: the two random walks are independent, right? so isn't this joint probability just the product of the two individual probabilities?

Comment: No they are not independent. In each step they move in the same direction, however with different step sizes.

Comment: Bound from above or from below? For what $t$? What properties of the bound(s) do you want to have?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in obtaining either an asymptotic or a realistic upper bound. I do not have a clear idea what to expect.  Also an argument for potential lower bounds would be nice.

For $t$ large enough. I think the bound should be in terms of $t, \sigma$.

For example an easy upper bound:  take $\sigma < 1/2$, then R2 has a bounded variance, while R1 has a variance $t^{1-2\sigma}$. The probability that both of them end up within the $\epsilon$-vicinity of zero is less than the probability that R1 ends up there, then we can use CLT.

Comment: So, what is the problem with your easy bound?

Comment: I suspect that it is far worse the asymptotic (assuming it exist). 
The reason I am asking this is for the potential implications of the Riemann hypothesis being false. In such a case, we would have two zeros at $s=\sigma+ i\gamma$ and $1-\sigma+ i\gamma$ with $\sigma <1/2$.

Interestingly, $\zeta(s)$ can be approximated quite well, at its zeros, by $\sum_{n<t} (-1)^n/n^s$ even within the critical strip. Furthermore, $\sum_{n<t} (-1)^n/n^s$ can be simulated using a random walk similar to R1.